# Retrieving the code parameter in OAuth redirected URL

Tags: jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

Our app, built by JHipster, uses an OAuth provider for user account management.  After signing in on the OAuth provider, I get

```
Request URL: http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/oidc?code=VC5asYS0etdW4lAPxJnKzKQZHLGMm5zff55W59wop03o&state=NPC69JnOxP8zotYYbakxFlzi4k1lFluGRtEro2BY4vc%3D
```

I find that the URL is handled in provision-okta-addon.sh.ejs file. How to retrieve the code parameter in the back end Java code so that it can be used to obtain an access token?

Or, is possible to obtain the access token in the Spring Security content?

Comment: You should be able to get the access token from Spring Security. Why do you need it? If you're trying to talk to another service with it, this post on WebClient might help. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/07/30/spring-webclient

Comment: Thanks Matt for your input. I, in fact, have figured it out after a lot of online research this afternoon. I forgot to update this post. I use @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient without a parameter to retrieve the access token. A web app is an OAuth client of another web app and it also customs the other web app REST APIs. That is the reason. I will take a look at the article.